# Indent in CSS using special format in title

Tags: css

I would like to achieve the following using CSS:

[image]

So far I was using following CSS-Code for moving single elements to the right:

```
[title^='10.10'] {
 position: relative;
 left: 10px;
    }
```

But I wanted to ask you guys, if you know any easier trick, maybe by the character style in the beginning of the title (if that is even possible in CSS) for bulk moving content from same hierarchical layer.

The problem beyond all of this is, that the elements themselves have varying ID's, which means I am pretty dependant on the dirty workaround with CSS.

A part of the HTML-code - seen with Dev-Tools:

[image]

Or is there maybe a way with JS and JQuery to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the dom structure please..we can try with some nth-child CSS props i guess

Comment: So all of these elements are `div`s with an id?

Comment: I believe it can be done with pure HTML + CSS, but please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think It is a valid question. Why the downgrade? He doesn't Know how to do It with html.. That's what he is asking. @AndrzejZiółek. Please make SO fun again!

Comment: As I understood this question OP doesn't have access to the HTML, because they mentioned being "dependant on the dirty workaround with CSS". Providing the HTML would make things a little more clear, but yeah, nothing downvote worthy imo

Comment: @Maharkus: You are right, all the elemnts are divs with an id - the problem is, that the id's variate with every reloading of the page.

Comment: @SteffPoint to be honest, I think if you only want to use CSS, you already have the easiest, if not the only possible solution. It's definitely possible with JS though.

Comment: The question is not *useful* without the HTML....we can't diagnose what we can't see so *that* would make it "worthy" of a downvote. This is like going to a mechanic and saying "My car won't run right, let me describe what it looks like".

Comment: I've added the HTML I see with Dev-Tools from Browser - I hope it helps.

Comment: @SteffPoint Does <tbody>...</tbody> (visible on your screenshot) contain more subcategories?

Comment: Images of Code are of **no use**. That's why we ask for functional demos.

Answer (score 4):

I would have used lists, here is a very short example, I used nested lists, you can change the `padding-left` on the `ul` element to increase or decrease the indentation.

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one line</li>
  <li>one line</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>one line</li>
      <li>one line</li>
      <li>one line</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>one line</li>
          <li>one line</li>
          <li>one line</li>
          <li>one line</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>one line</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I don't even have access to the HTML Code. It is an existing application, called Polarion, which I am trying to customize to our users :)

Comment: There is no kind of index.html. The GUI seems to be implemented by server's side if I got it correctly

Comment: @SteffPoint Sorry I misunderstood your question, could you show us a part of the generated html code? Are the divs of each subcategory nested inside the parent category? (in that case you could just use something like `div > * {padding-left : 10px`)